# Insert an React Component from a new WebSite to a old WebSite ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, reactjs

I have two WebSite, V1 & V2

I want to integrate a ReminderButton (create with ReactJS) from v2 to v1,
Is in ASP.NET,

```
    react component integration :

    <div class="pull-right" id="mainDiv"></div>

    <script>
            MySiteConfiguration.configure({
                websiteUrl: '@(Request.Url.Scheme)' + '://' + '@(Request.Url.Host)' + ':' + '@Request.Url.Port'
            });

            makeQuickRemindersListButton({
                selector: '#mainDiv', 
                pageSize: 10,
                currentUser: { reference: 65, name: 'GAELLE', type: 'backoffice' },
            });
</script>
```

I Need insert this in the Master page of V1,

I configure all web.config for link the 2 version of my website so now in my V1 masterPage i Can do this

```
<a href='<%= string.Format("{0}Labs/ReminderQuickView", MySiteV1Module.Parametre.MySiteV2Back.URL) %>' target="_blank">
                                <div class="memu-icon sprite-user_edit"></div>
                                goToReminder</a>
```

What's the best approach for integrate the react component from V2 into the master page of V1?

Thanks and sorry for my english.

Comment: not enough detail here to give a useful answer, it's not fully clear what the scenario is. You want the button from the first site to request something from the second one? Or cause a redirect? Have you tried anything yet? What happened?

Comment: I tried to explain a little better. thanks.